# Check if feed is fetched successfully

Tags: feed

I am trying to fetch specific post feed from my one side to another one.
every thing works fine, only thing I need to check is that if the feed is not successfully fetched by custom field, it should return an error or custom message.

Here is the code which I have tried sofar, I am trying to check the post title length, if it is greater than zero, display feed else, return error. But its not working.
any ideas.

```
    <?php
    include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php');
    $feed = 'http://ar.mysite.com/feed/?translate_id=P1511'; 
    $rss = fetch_feed($feed);
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(1);
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);  echo $maxitems ;
    //if ($rss_items):
    echo "<ul class='feedclass'>\n";
    foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) :
    $feedtitle = $item->get_title() ; // echo $feedtitle ;

    if (strlen($feedtitle) > 0) { 
    printf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a><p>%s</p></li>',$item->get_permalink(),$item->get_title(),$item->get_description() );
    }
    else {
    echo 'This recipe is not translated yet';
    }
    endforeach;
    echo "</ul>\n";
    //endif;
    ?>
```

below code adds the translate_id in query_var

```
    /**
    *
    * @param array $query_vars
    * @return array $query_vars
    */ 
    function my_query_vars( $query_vars ) 
    {
    $query_vars[] = 'translate_id';
    return $query_vars;
    }
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );

    /**
    * Filter the feed by the 'translate_id' meta key 
    *
    * @param WP_Query object $query
    * @return void 
    */ 
    function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) 
    {
    // only for feeds
    if( $query->is_feed && $query->is_main_query() ) 
    {
    // check if the translate_id variable is set 
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['translate_id'] ) 
    && ! empty( $query->query_vars['translate_id'] ) )
    {

    // if you only want to allow 'alpha-numerics':
    $translate_id =  preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $query->query_vars['translate_id'] ); 

    // set up the meta query for translate_id
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'translate_id' );
    $query->set( 'meta_value', $translate_id );
    }
    } 
    }

    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts' );
```

Answer (score 1):

[`fetch_feed()` returns a WP_Error()](http://wpseek.com/fetch_feed/) if the feed in question does not exist or fails for whatever reason. If we're only checking for failure we can check if the returned object `is_wp_error()`.

```
if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ){
    // Assume the best, show feed
}
else{
    // Assume the worst, show message
}
```

If the feed does return valid but is empty, we can do what you're currently doing which is to try and get items from the valid feed:

`$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(1);`

If `$maxitems` is empty or 0, then we know the feed is a valid, but empty.

Comment: empty feed is also a valid feed ;)

Comment: @MarkKaplun Good point, I've updated my answer with code reference keeping that in mind.

Comment: Thank you Howday for the reply, I dont know what is happening here but when I fetch the feed with a valid custom key, it returns the correct translated post, but when I check with an invalid custom key(same post), it just returns the original post - without translation?

Comment: It probably has to do with code that you haven't posted. I'm not sure what `translate_id` is or how it's used. Are you using a custom feed template or is this URL generated by a plugin?

Comment: Hi Howdy, I have updated the code for your reference.